# Postgres PL/JAVA: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error after loading JAR file in database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, pljava

I am getting the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: error inside Postgres when running a function that calls a JAR file I have loaded.  I have installed and configured PL/JAVA (including the delivered examples) in my database and can run the examples to success.  I am not attempting to load/install my first JAR, but I am doing something wrong.

My host controls the OS version:  CentOS 6.8.  Postgres is version 8.4.

I am attempting to install my own very simple java class, which is a derivative of the delivered example Parameters.addOne class.  All my code is in /tmp.  Here are the steps I've followed:

Doug.java:

```
    package com.msmetric;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Time;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class Doug {
      public static int addOne(int value) {
        return value + 1;
       }
    }
```

2. Compile Doug.java using 'javac Doug.java' succeeds.
3. Create JAR file with Doug.class file in it using 'jar -cvf Doug.jar Doug.class.  This works fine.

Now I load the JAR file into Postgres (public schema), change the classpath, create the function that calls the JAR, then attempt to run at psql prompt.

1. Run sqlj.install_jar from psql:

   ```
   select sqlj.install_jar('file:/tmp/Doug.jar','Doug',false);
   ```
2. Set the classpath inside Postgres (from psql prompt postgres=#):

   ```
   select sqlj.set_classpath('public','Doug');
   ```
3. Create the function that calls the JAR.  This create function code is taken directly from the examples.ddr file that came with PL/JAVA.  I simply changed org.postgres to com.msmetric.

   ```
   create or replace function addone(int) returns int as 'com.msmetric.Doug.addOne(java.lang.Integer)' language java;
   ```

Now with the JAR loaded and function created, I attempt to run it.  This function should simply add 1 to the number provided.

```
    select addone(3);
```

Results:
ERROR:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.msmetric.Doug

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry I didn't see your question sooner. Underneath all the exotic details (PostgreSQL, PL/Java, schemas, classpaths...), there's just a bit of basic Java going on here: if a jar file contains a class `Doug.class` in package `com.msmetric`, its path within the jar has to reflect that: it has to be `com/msmetric/Doug.class`. Otherwise, it won't be found.

You can set up that whole structure step by step:

`javac Doug.java
mkdir com
mkdir com/msmetric
mv Doug.class com/msmetric/
jar -cvf Doug.jar com/msmetric/Doug.class`

Or, you can let `javac` do more of the work for you:

`mkdir classes
javac -d classes Doug.java
jar -cvf Doug.jar -C classes .`

When you give `javac` a `-d`*directory* option, instead of just writing class files next to their `.java` sources, it will put them all in their proper places under the directory you named, and then you can just tell `jar` to change into that directory and slurp them all up (don't overlook the `.` at the end of that `jar` command).

Once you fix that, if you retry your original steps, you'll see that you now get a different error:

```
ERROR:  Unable to find static method com.msmetric.Doug.addOne with signature (Ljava/lang/Integer;)I
```

That happens because you declared the function in `Doug.java` with `int addOne(int value)` (that is, taking a primitive `int` argument), but you declared it in SQL with `returns int as 'com.msmetric.Doug.addOne(java.lang.Integer)'` taking an `Integer` object.

Once you correct that:

```
create or replace function addone(int) returns int as 'com.msmetric.Doug.addOne(int)' language java;
```

you'll be able to see:

```
# select addone(3);
 addone 
--------
      4
(1 row)
```

If you happen to see this belated answer, may I ask what version of PL/Java you are using? That's one detail you didn't mention. If it is older than 1.5.0, there are newer features that can help you out. For one, you can just annotate that function:

```
@Function
public static int addOne(int value) {
  return value + 1;
}
```

and have `javac` spit out not only the `Doug.class` file but also a `pljava.ddr` file with your SQL function declaration already written correctly (no mixing up argument types!). There is a way to include that `.ddr` file into the jar you create so that you can just call `sqlj.install_jar` with the last parameter `true` so it runs the commands in the `.ddr` and your functions are ready to use. There's a Hello, world example [in the docs](http://tada.github.io/pljava/use/hello.html) that shows more of how it's done.

Cheers,
-Chap